# Firebase automatic login after reloading Ionic app/page

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

Back when I was using Parse, it seemed like the SDK would store the session data locally and the user didn't have to log in again after refreshing the page (or exiting the mobile app). This doesn't seem to be the case with Firebase/Angularfire; everytime I refresh my web page, the authentication data gets lots. This seems like really basic and important functionality that I would be surprised the awesome people at Firebase haven't implemented. Am I missing something?

For completeness; here is my code in app.run():

```
// ASG  june 2016 - Upgrade firebase SDK
firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);

// login as anonymous if not already logged in
var currentUser = $firebaseAuth().$getAuth();
if (currentUser) {
    console.log("Signed in as:", currentUser);
} else {
    console.log("Not logged in; going to log in as anonymous");
    $firebaseAuth().$signInAnonymously().then(function(authData) {
        console.log("Signed in anonymously as:", authData.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Anonymous authentication failed:", error);
    });
}

// register the on auth callback
$firebaseAuth().$onAuthStateChanged(function(authData) {
    if (authData) {
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
        if(typeof($rootScope.userProfile) == "undefined"){
           $rootScope.userProfile = FirebaseProfileService.getUserProfile(authData.uid, false); 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auth token is persisted between page/app reloads. But it will often need to get a new refresh token when the page reloads, which requires a round-trip to the Firebase servers. Since this takes time, the initial `getAuth()` may return `null` while that process is ongoing.

```
var currentUser;

$firebaseAuth().$onAuthStateChanged(function(authData) {
    if (authData) {
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
        currentUser = authData.currentUser;
        if(typeof($rootScope.userProfile) == "undefined"){
           $rootScope.userProfile = FirebaseProfileService.getUserProfile(authData.uid, false); 
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("Not logged in; going to log in as anonymous");
        currentUser = null;
        $firebaseAuth().$signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Anonymous authentication failed:", error);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase absolutely presists authData and has a lot of goodness you hardly find elsewhere. Therefore, I don't see any logical reason behind calling getAuth() here as you can easily get the authData from the onAuthStateChanged listener. In this case, you may need to remove your operations of getting currentUser using getAuth() and move your ELSE condition to onAuthStateChanged if you want to sign up users as anonymous in case no AuthData was found, and then you will be good to go, I hope. Hope that works.

Comment: How do I get data about the current logged in user without using getAuth ? In other states where I want to check if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: I'm just a bit confused why getAuth would return null if the user is already logged in and this data is persisted.

Comment: I think it's because you put it in the app.run () which sometimes leads to race conditions, but in different states that would be tackled by a separate controllers and services would work just fine. Again, I am just thinking and speculating here nothing is tested from my side. But give a try and let me know.